# Mapping Antarctica in R

Tags: r, maps

I'm trying to plot some coordinates that stretches across Antarctica, and since I really don't care about the rest of the world, I'm trying to find a way to plot just the Antarctic continent with R (i.e. showing a view from the south pole). Problem is, nobody seems to care about Antarctica and most of the stuff I'm able to find about how to plot coordinates in R straight up cut away the continent because it gets warped in the Mercator projection...

and now I'm completely stuck. Any advices on how to approach the problem? Or helpful sources?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a UTM projection in conjunction with [leaflet](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/projections.html)?

Comment: Tbh I was trying to use mapPlot but I'm not sure if then I can add a new set of coordinates on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform to a polar stereographic projection system.

```
require(maptools)
shp = wrld_simpl[which(wrld_simpl$NAME=="Antarctica"),]
shp = spTransform(shp,"+init=EPSG:3031")
plot(shp)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I've seen this a couple of times, but in this way I can't add a grid can't I?

Comment: You can add whatever you like but that wasn't in your question